# Python. Поиск записи в базе данных

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Такой код:

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='ip', charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `ip`')

results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
for key in results:
    if key == '1':
       print('naiden')
db.close()
```

БД:
[image: БД]

Надо, чтобы начался поиск записи `'1'`. Если найдет, то: `print('naiden')`

Comment: А вы знаете что такое phpmyadmin?  судя по вашему вопросу, вы не отделяете phpmyadmin от СУБД Mysql. Я бы  вам сначала посоветовал бы разобраться в этих понятиях. Причем ваш вопрос не относится к python, скорее к языку запросов Mysql.

Comment: @CGduuDE, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 1):

Почти все правильно, кроме данной строки:

```
if key == '1':
```

Исправлена на:

```
if row["IP logins"] == '1':
```

---

Вот полный исправленный код:

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='ip', charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `ip`')

rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
for row in rows:
    if row["IP logins"] == '1':
       print('naiden')
db.close()
```

Больше информации можно найти [здесь](https://pythontic.com/database/mysql/query%20a%20table)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='ip', charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `ip`')

results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
for key in results:
    if key[0] == '1': //надо искать по столбцам - в данном случае "IP logins" Это 0 столбец
       print('naiden')
db.close()
```